# in azure logic apps how to retrieve messages from dead letter queue from azure service bus topics

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-logic-apps, azure-servicebus-topics

I have built a logic app which receives messages from azure service bus topic in peek lock mode.if the message is not processed for 2 deliver count the message will be moved to dead letter queue.till this it goes well in logic app.

So now i have to process the messages from dead letter queue by resubmitting the messages from dead letter queue to topic automatically and receive it in logic app.please help me out to implement this only in logic app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your Logic App, select the Service Bus connector which receives messages from topic's subscription. Then click on `Show advanced options` and select `Subscription type` option `DeadLetter`:

[image]

For queues, you can just go to Queue name field select `Enter custom value` and put the value in the format `myqueue/$DeadLetterQueue`:

[image]

Now you can add a step to submit the DLQ messages to any queue or topic.